# I am curious about apns feedback service

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am curious about apns feedback service.

Question 1)
Will the tokens returned by my query to the feedback service be removed from the feedback service immediately?
If I query the feedback service and the token 'A' is returned, will not it return 'A' when I query again?

Question 2)
Can device tokens be duplicated?
I looked up the feedback service and deleted the returned device token.
However, sometimes the same device token value is collected after deletion.

Comment: did you find any tutorial on it?